# Object starts to rotate prior to keyframe instruction

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm concerned that I'm making procedural errors, but, if at a glance, is there an explanation ?
I have an object that goes across the screen, and it works fine, but an object that's perched atop it I want to rotate at a certain point, specifically, at frame 42.  For some reason that I'm missing, it starts to rotate much earlier (approx. frame 10).  A solution would be appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iHqWbhVB2LLMW5kOaHvHVtBFxMkTT7z4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To ensure an object "does nothing" let's call it zero, would have a keyframe on frame 1 -> 0 and the next at frame 41 -> 0    Look at the graph editor https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/editing.html#handle-type  chances are you have kf at 1 and next at 42 & hence it starts interpolating a rotation way before 42.  Sure this has been covered will look for a duplicate Q / A.

Answer (score 1):

This is the X rotation curve of your empty, as you can see it begins to rotate at frame 1:

[image]

If you want it to begin at frame 42, you need to move the frame 42 keyframe, duplicate the frame 1 keyframe and put it at 42:

[image]